# getting gridfs file in insert hook

Tags: python, eve

I am making a file indexing service using eve.

All my collections are of the type:

```
DOMAIN = {
"file_collection" : {
    ...
    'schema' : {
        'file': {'type': 'media'},
        'meta': {'type': 'dict',
            schema: {...whatever it is I want to index...}
            }
        }
    }, 
}
```

I would like to use an on_insert hook to open the file , extract some data and populate this document's meta dictionary.

I have not been able to access or find any gridFS object in the eve application object: How can I access the document contents?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is what I learnt during my subsequent research:

```
from eve import Eve
from flask import current_app 
from eve.io.mongo.media import GridFSMediaStorage


def file_collection_on_insert(documents):
    gridfs = GridFSMediaStorage(app=current_app)
    #do something with gridfs: eg: gridfs.get(file_id)

app = Eve()
app.on_insert += file_collection_on_insert
app.run()
```

===================

Edit:

Event quicker and easier access to media:

```
from flask import current_app as app

def file_collection_on_insert(documents):
    #get the file_id
    app.media.get(file_id)
```

Voilà!